Scrolling Issue on Touch Devices Due to OrbitControls Component in a React App
I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to scroll through my application using touch gestures. Upon debugging, I've identified that the culprit might be the OrbitControls component. Despite extensive research, I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem.
Essentially, I'm using the OrbitControls component in my application, but it seems to be interfering with the ability to scroll through the application content on touch devices. I've tried various approaches to resolve this issue but haven't had any success.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
I tried setting enabled=false, hoping to resolve the issue, but it didn't work as expected.
import { OrbitControls, PerspectiveCamera, View } from "@react-three/drei";
import Lights from "./Lights";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import IPhone from "./IPhone";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Loader } from "./Loader";

export const ModelView = ({
  index,
  groupRef,
  gsapType,
  controlRef,
  setRotationState,
  item,
  size,
}) => {
  return (
    <View
      index={index}
      id={gsapType}
      className={` w-full h-full absolute ${
        index == 2 ? "right-[-100%]" : ""
      } `}
    >
      {/* Ambient Light  ddd*/}
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[0, 0, 4]} />

      <Lights />
      <OrbitControls
        makeDefault
        ref={controlRef}
        enableZoom={false}
        enablePan={false}
        rotateSpeed={0.4}
        target={new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)}
        onEnd={(e) => {
          setRotationState(controlRef.current.getAzimuthalAngle());
        }}
      />

      <group
        ref={groupRef}
        name={`${index === 1} ? "small" : "large"`}
        position={[0, 0, 0]}
      >
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <IPhone
            scale={index === 1 ? [15, 15, 15] : [17, 17, 17]}
            item={item}
            size={size}
          />
        </Suspense>
      </group>
    </View>
  );
};


Maybe add css to block user input for mobile devices (or all devices) on canvas with threejs. Because orbit controls prevent events to buble up (using e.preventDefault), so it's blocking scrolling.
Mobile -
touch-action: none;

Desktop (maybe you will need this also for mobile):
pointer-events: none;

